React state not being changed properly when passed to child
fairly simple issue here that I cannot seem to fix. My understanding and previous practice of using react is if you want to change a state from a parent within a child, it should be passed to the child. Upon clicking on the main "Project" div, the state gets changed to 'true' and the modal appears, but when attempting to press the 'X' within 'ProjectModal', the state does not change to false, thus not closing the modal.
What am i missing here? i've done with numerous times before yet i cannot fix this issue.
Projects.tsx:
interface ModalProps extends Project {
    setModal: (modal: boolean) => void,
    modal: boolean
}
export default function Projects(props: Project) {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState<boolean>(false)
    let showOrHideModal = modal ? 'inline' : 'hidden'

    return (
        <div onClick={() => setModal(true)}>
          <div className={showOrHideModal}>
            <ProjectModal {...props} setModal={setModal} modal={modal} />
          </div>
        </div>
  )
}

function ProjectModal(props: ModalProps) {

    return (
             <X onClick={() => {
                console.log('X clicked');
                props.setModal(false);
                console.log(props.modal)
             }} />
    )
}

attempted different methods of switching state, props.setModal(false), props.setModal(!props.modal)... been googling with no luck.

How is ProjectModal getting the setModal prop passed to it? In your example code, we don't see how ProjectModal is being rendered.

missed that when refining code, just added the modal component to Projects

It is because the event is propagating up. When you click on the X in the modal, you also are clicking on the div that has the setModal(true) click handler logic.
You need to change your DOM structure so the modal isn't a child of the element that opens the modal, stop the event from propagating up (e.g. stopPropagation), or use a state structure rather than a boolean.

Your click event is most likely bubbling up to the div that contains the handler to set modal to true.
So two click handlers are firing - first setting to false, second setting back to true. These are most likely batched so that you never see the result of the first call.
You have two options to correct this problem.

Use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from bubbling up to the other handler.

<X 
  onClick={(e) => { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    props.setModal(false);
  }}
/>


Move the Modal out of the div with the click handler so that the click events do not overlap

return (
  <>
    <div onClick={() => setModal(true)} />
    <div className={showOrHideModal}>
      <ProjectModal {...props} setModal={setModal} modal={modal} />
    </div>
  </>
)

